# Bash script to list items in directory by size

Tags: bash, shell-script, disk-usage

How do I write a script that for each argument, the script should display the largest item in the directory along with its size. Something like this:

```
[user]$ maxls /boot 2> /dev/null | sort -n
1024 /boot/grub2/themes/stars
8101 /boot/grub2/pic.png
```

Comment: Please clarify and bring into agreement the description and expected results example.  For one thing, your description says the largest item (singular) in the directory while the example shows 2 items for the one command line argument `/boot`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
for dir
do
    [ -d "$dir" ] || continue
    du -hs "$dir"/* | sort -hr | sed  1q
done
```

Comment: Note that `du -h` and `sort -h` are GNU extensions.

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I'm currently working on a paper entitled "GNU Extensions Considered Harmful."  So seductive, yet so non-portable!  I'm a portability nut but those damn GNU Extensions keep sneaking in!  **Agreed, this script would be universally portable if the `h` option is removed from `du` and `sort`.**

Comment: Well, by that yard stick, I am pretty sure bash isn't POSIX either...  not that I would wish basic Bourne shell on anyone (or *shudder* ksh)

Comment: Heh, not by a long shot in `bash` mode but if started as `sh` then `bash` conforms to POSIX 1003.1.  However `dash` conforms to POSIX 1003.2. That, and the size difference, are the reasons why I always (on Debian etc) set /bin/sh to /bin/dash and write all scripts for #!/bin/sh, unless the solution requires a  _GNU Extension_ .   I think GNU is one of the greatest free software projects _ever_!  The extensions problem is in the code programming, not so much interactive usage.  The title of my paper is a play on Dijkstra's famous 1968 letter "GOTO Considered Harmful."

Comment: How do I go about recursively diplaying the subdirectories and their size as well?

Comment: I'm not even sure if this answer satisfies your original question.  There are unresolved differences between the text and example in your question.  There are many ways to do the recursion that you're asking about.  Maybe you can ask this as a new question and be as specific as possible in the description _and_ example.  I'm feeling kind of beat-up on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` I'd go with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find;

my %biggest_file_in;
my %biggest_file_size_in;

sub max_in_path {
    my ($dir) = @_;
    return unless -f;
    if ( -s > ( $biggest_file_size_in{$dir} // 0 ) ) {

        $biggest_file_in{$dir}      = $File::Find::name;
        $biggest_file_size_in{$dir} = -s;
    }
}


my ($path_to_search) = @ARGV;
die "Specify a path" unless $path_to_search;
foreach my $dir ( glob("$path_to_search/*") ) {
    next unless -d $dir;
    find( sub { max_in_path($dir) }, $dir );
    print $dir, ":", $biggest_file_in{$dir}, " =>",
        $biggest_file_size_in{$dir}, "\n";
}


print "Largest files in individual directories (sorted):\n";
foreach my $dir ( sort 
                     { $biggest_file_size_in{$b} <=> $biggest_file_size_in{$a} } 
                         keys  %biggest_file_size_in ) { 
    print "$dir $biggest_file_in{$dir} $biggest_file_size_in{$dir}\n";
}
```

Note - works for all directories under specified directory. (e.g:  `myfind.pl /data` will search `/data/*` - but ignore any files present in `/data`);

Comment: So everyone's getting more and more off-topic… BASH.

Comment: ... Is installed by nearly as many places as perl.  And still isn't the tool for the job,  given you rely on du or find or sort. Which means multiple not-bash programs, where my answer is only one.

Comment: Makes sense. You can even use some `perl << EOF` to make it bash. Added to '42 ways to make your Linux teacher angry' (just kidding).

Comment: @Arthur2e5 providing alternative approaches is perfectly fine, it doesn't make the answer off topic. On the other hand, complaining about "others getting your rep" is very much off topic.

Comment: @terdon I take that as a joke, *Arthur2e5's evil*.

Answer (score 0):

The `zsh` shell has builtin support for that:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/stat &&
for dir {
  largest=(${dir:-.}/**/*(NDOL[1]))
  (($#largest)) || largest=${dir:-.}
  zstat -A size +size -- "$largest" &&
    print -r -- $size $largest
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
# m_all [dir=.]...: lists the biggest file in *all* the directories.
#   du options can be specified using $DU_OPTS; the recommend value is '-h'.
m_all(){ find "$@" -type f -print0 | du $DU_OPTS --files0-from=-; }
# maxls: for each argument, list the biggest $maxls_n items.
#   If $maxls_n is undefined or empty, use 1.
#   Additional arguments to pass to m_all can be defined in the array mallargs; see examples below.
maxls(){ local i; for i; do m_all "$i" "${mallargs[@]}" | sort -h | tail -n "${maxls_n:-1}"; done; }
#_Example:
# list the biggest file for /bin and /usr respectively
maxls /bin /usr
# list the biggest 5 files for /home and /root
maxls_n=5 maxls /home /root
# Let maxls count only *.avi, *.svg and *.mp4:
mallargs=(-iregex '.*\.\(avi\|svg\|mp4\).*')
# And run it against ~/Anime
maxls ~/Anime; mallagrs=() # clear that setting
# And use m_all to list the biggest five logs:
DU_OPTS=-h m_all /var -name '*.log*' | sort -h | tail -n 5
```

And you can even add `find` filters!

**Edit**: Added for each. Thanks to RobertL for pointing that out. And documentation.

If you want this as a script, create a new file which says `#!/bin/bash`, copy those lines with `(){` into it and then add `maxls "$@"`. Personally I don't like filling up my `~/bin` with super-trivial scripts though.

---

#### Explanation/changelog

From the example we can see files in subdirs, and the thing is invoked with an extra `sort -h`. Since the whole directory is definitely no smaller than the files contained in it, I conclude the *items* is limited to files only.

From this point I got the initial solution, now called `m_all`. We can't know which the largest ones are unless we sort them, so an extra `tail` pass was added in the initial example.

With some patching, this is version 3, but this is buggy, since the asker wants *for each argument*. I renamed it to `m_all`, leaving a wrapper called `maxls` since I assume the old one still has some use and I want to minimize my changes (v4). As what I always do, I left a handful of switches to change its behavior. After that, as you can see, documentation was added (v5-7).

Please be aware that with the *foreach* behavior, it is generally meaningless to use any `tail` or `sort` after the whole thing is done. You have to use `sort` every time you get those output. `tail` does print last lines for each file given, but it's going to make the code super long.

Comment: Hmmm. This answer is even more ambiguous than the question.  And it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @RobertL Basically it's the input, output and syntax he asked for. `du` with `-s` is definitely wrong since he asked for files in the example.

Comment: You've significantly modified your answer since my comment. The question doesn't contain the word **"file"**, and `du -s` shows sizes for files as well as directories.   To be accurate, the question asks for a **script** (not function) which takes arguments that the script will interpret as **directories**, and the script should print the size and name of the largest **item (singular)** **in** the directory.  I didn't see that in your original answer.  You may interpret **in** to mean "under" the directory, but items in subdirs are not actually **in** the given directory.

Comment: Your confusion is the reason I asked the questioner to clarify the ambiguities.  The example in the question doesn't match the text of the question.  I don't think it's a good idea to vote down based on different interpretations of an unclear and ambiguous question.

Comment: You really don't need to give a complete explanation of all your changes, or keep crediting the same person over and over. It should be easy for someone to read your answer and understand it, without needing the complete history of how it got there

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Well, it's only some reply to his *significantly modified*, and some deleted comments on my ability to take constructive criticism. It was written with some anger actually :/ [APPEND] For anger, refer to the downvote part, which basically means 'hey you are definitely wrong'.

Comment: This site aims to be more of a wiki than a forum. Think of the next user who will read this answer a year from now. None of the "changelog" will be remotely useful to them. Nobody knows what the initial solution was or how it was changed. Please write your answers in such a way as to be understandable to someone who reads the current version only.